# How to get byte size of multibyte string

Tags: c, string, character-encoding, size, multibyte

How do I get the byte size of a multibyte-character string in Visual C? Is there a function or do I have to count the characters myself?

Or, more general, how do I get the right byte size of a TCHAR string?

Solution:

```
_tcslen(_T("TCHAR string")) * sizeof(TCHAR)
```

EDIT:
I was talking about null-terminated strings only.

Comment: Your code is correct, for calculating the size, in bytes, of the string. The statement "works for ... char and wchar_t ... but not for multibyte-character strings" is confused, however.

Comment: So multibyte-character strings don't contain null bytes?

Comment: @Tilka: They could, but you'd need to know the length in some other fashion, such as storing it in an integer that comes with the string. Null terminated strings, which are what one typically encounters (and what _tcslen, strlen, etc. require), do not contain null bytes, except for the null terminator, of course.

Comment: To be more precise...  The multibyte strings can contain null bytes, but not null characters. ie, the first 8-bits of a character could be all-zeros, or the last 8-bits could well be all-zeros, however, if the whole character is all-zeros, then that constitutes "end-of-string" in this case.

Comment: @Arafangion: But isn't a char only 8 bits wide?

Comment: @Arafangion: within the domain of Microsoft terminology, a multi-byte character string is not expected to have embedded null bytes -- otherwise, is there an example you can show?

Comment: @Thanatos: Interesting, however that statement implies that there are no multibyte string encodings that have embedded null bytes? Is that correct?

Comment: @Tilka: A char is not necessarily 8 bits wide. It does, however, have a size of 1 regardless of how many bits it has, as per C standard.  For example, a char could be 12, or 16 bits wide, depending on architecture and compiler options. (I've heard of char being 6 bits wide in some C compilers on some platforms, but that means that it can't hold a value between 0 and 128, and so would be itself incompatible with the spec, at least I hope it is!)

Comment: @Tilka: If that detail is important, look for the CHAR_BIT, CHAR_BITS, CHARBIT, or related macro. (I can't remember which one applies here)

Comment: `char` must always be at least 8 bits. In this question, which appears to be regarding MS APIs, `char` is always 8 bits. And since the MS APIs only take pointers, and not a pointer/size, they must assume that there are no embedded nulls for the MBCS part of the API. (And no embedded U+0000 for the Unicode part)

Comment: RTFM C. A multibyte string can never contain a null byte except as the terminating null. This is really basic and no one seems to get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax%28VS.71%29.aspx), `_tcslen` corresponds to `strlen` when `_MBCS` is defined. `strlen` will return the number of *bytes* in the string. If you use `_tcsclen` that corresponds to `_mbslen` which returns the number of multibyte *characters*.

Also, multibyte strings do not (AFAIK) contain embedded nulls, no.

I would question the use of a multibyte encoding in the first place, though... unless you're supporting a legacy app, there's no reason to choose multibyte over Unicode.

Comment: UTF-8 strings don't contain embedded nulls (specifically: the only place a 0 byte ever occurs is representing the 0 code point, so if that's your terminator then you can search for it byte-wise). I'm not sure whether UTF-16 is considered a "multibyte encoding" in this context, but it can certainly contain 0 *bytes*, just not 0 double-bytes. I think SHIFT-JIS doesn't use 0 bytes except when encoding 0. Lots of encodings in the world, but I'm not sure what's possible within Windows locales...

Comment: That's a bit muddled: UTF-8 strings can contain nulls, *if* you're storing the size in something other than a null terminator. Null terminated strings cannot contain nulls, because they're null terminated. A null terminated UTF-8 string cannot contain nulls for the same reason. That said, I cannot think of any useful purpose to putting a null in a UTF-8 string other than to terminate it.

Answer (score 10):

Let's see if I can clear this up:

"Multi-byte character string" is a vague term to begin with, but in the world of Microsoft, it typically meants "not ASCII, and not UTF-16". Thus, you could be using some character encoding which might use 1 byte per character, or 2 bytes, or possibly more. As soon as you do, the number of characters in the string != the number of bytes in the string.

Let's take UTF-8 as an example, even though it isn't used on MS platforms. The character é is encoded as "c3 a9" in memory -- thus, two bytes, but 1 character. If I have the string "thé", it's:

```
text: t  h  é     \0
mem:  74 68 c3 a9 00
```

This is a "null terminated" string, in that it ends with a null. If we wanted to allow our string to have nulls in it, we'd need to store the size in some other fashion, such as:

```
struct my_string
{
    size_t length;
    char *data;
};
```

... and a slew of functions to help deal with that. (This is sort of how `std::string` works, quite roughly.)

For null-terminated strings, however, `strlen()` will compute their size *in bytes*, not characters. (There are other functions for counting characters) `strlen` just counts the number of bytes before it sees a 0 byte -- nothing fancy.

Now, "wide" or "unicode" strings in the world of MS refer to UTF-16 strings. They have similar problems in that the number of bytes != the number of characters. (Also: the number of bytes / 2 != the number of characters) Let look at thé again:

```
text:   t      h      é      \0
shorts: 0x0074 0x0068 0x00e9 0x0000
mem:    74 00  68 00  e9 00  00 00
```

That's "thé" in UTF-16, stored in little endian (which is what your typical desktop is). Notice all the 00 bytes -- these trip up strlen. Thus, we call `wcslen`, which looks at it as 2-byte `short`s, not single bytes.

Lastly, you have `TCHAR`s, which are one of the above two cases, depending on if `UNICODE` is defined. `_tcslen` will be the appropriate function (either `strlen` or `wcslen`), and `TCHAR` will be either `char` or `wchar_t`. `TCHAR` was created to ease the move to UTF-16 in the Windows world.

Comment: "(Also: the number of bytes / 2 != the number of characters)"

How so?

Comment: @Tilka: That's the way UTF-16 encodes characters. UTF-16 can encode more than 65,536 different characters, so it should be clear that 2 bytes are not enough. UTF-16 encodes many characters as just 2 bytes, but must use 4 for some, in a form known as "Surrogate pairs" (See Wikipedia's article on UTF-16.)

Comment: Ah yes, I confused it with UCS-2. Nice explanation btw, but the other answer was straight to the point.