# Length of Greek character string is larger than it should be

Tags: c, string, char

I'm writing a program and I take a string of Greek characters as input and when I print its len, it outputs its double. For example, if ch="ΑΒ"(greek characters) or ch="αβ",

`printf("%d",strlen(ch));` outputs 4 instead of 2. And if ch="ab", it outputs 2. What's going on?

Comment: Two words.  "Character Encoding"

Comment: each greek character will be encoded as two bytes, but strlen doesn't know anything about how the string is encoded.  It is just looking for the null terminator.  This is a good explanation of your dilemma: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3358539/1212725

Comment: The fun thing is that there is nothing in C that prohibits using a one-byte Greek encoding (the Windows one or MacGreek, and possibly more). Then you'd get your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mbstowcs() function to convert multybite string to wide-character string. And then use wcslen() to determine it's length.

Comment: Or just use `mbsrtowcs()` with a null destination (it will return the number of wide characters it would have written).

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your string is encoded using variable-width character encoding.

In the good old days, we only bothered with 128 different characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and some commas and brackets and control things.  Everything was taken care of in 7 bits, and we called it ASCII.  Then that wasn't enough and we added some other things like letters with lines or dots on top, and we went to 8 bits (1 byte) and could do any of 256 characters in one byte. (Although people's ideas of what should go in those extra 128 slots varied widely, based on what was most useful in their language - see comment from usr2564301 - and you then had to say whose version you were using for what should be in those extra slots.)

If you had 2 characters in your string, it would be 2 bytes long (plus a null terminator perhaps), always.

But then people woke up to the fact that English isn't the only language in the world, and there were in fact thousands of letters in hundreds of languages around the globe.  Now what to do?

Well, we could say there are only about 65,000 characters that interest us, and encode all letters in two bytes.  There are some encoding formats that do this.  A two-letter string will then always be 4 bytes (um, perhaps with some byte order mark at the front, and maybe a null terminator at the end).  Two problems: a) not very backwards compatible with ASCII, and b) wasteful of bytes if most text is stuff that is in the good ol' ASCII character set anyway.

Step in UTF-8, which I'll wager is what your string is using for its encoding, or something similar.  ASCII characters, like 'a' and 'b', are encoded with one byte, and more exotic characters (--blush-- from an English-speaking perspective) take up more than one byte, of which the first byte is to say "what follows is to be taken along with this byte to represent a letter".  So you get variable-width encoding.  So the length of a two-letter string will be at least two bytes, but if it includes non-ASCII characters, it'll be more.

Comment: Nice summary, except that the step from 7-bit to 8-bit ASCII was quite a lot more ... *involving*. Every single pc clone creator and every Latin-based community – and a few that are not – took advantage of that *wealth* of 128 Totally Free characters to stuff in what they wanted and promote their own system as The Definitive New ASCII for the Next 100 Years. Browsers today *still* must have a "set character set manually" override to sort out that mess.