# Can't turn Greek to Latin characters in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm writing a program that turns Greek characters into Latin characters. Here's the code for a simplified version:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {
  char list1[]="αβ",list2[]="ab",ch='p';
  printf("Gimme string: ");
  while(ch!='\n')
  {
    ch=getchar();
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        if(ch==list1[i]){
          printf("%c",list2[i]);
          break;
        }
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If my input is "αβ", it's supposed to output "ab" but it outputs "aba". I also tried making list1 a 2-dimensional array, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: CONSTRUCTIVE (*in spite of how it sounds*): "Don't declare variables like that, and use whitespace around operators. Your code is a very small huge mess."

Comment: *"doesn't work."* is not useful problem description. What values are you seeing and what are you expecting when you run the code in debugger? Read on [mcve] to make your question more informative.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `wchar` instead of `char`

Comment: just an observation but you only read a single character with ch=getch() and you only print a single character with printf("%c" . I have no idea where the extra "ba" is coming from but it implies your encoding is larger that 3 bytes per character UTF-32  perhaps

Comment: I see you did not comment or accepted any answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48689862/2564301) on the same subject. Did you not see the answers? Do you not agree with any of them? ... Do you understand them? (The latter because this question suggests you do not.)

Comment: What encoding is used for string literals on your platform?  If you're using ISO-8859-7, this should work, but on UTF-8 platforms, ` α` and `β` are encoded using more than one `char` each.  You'll want to move to wide-character strings in that case.

Comment: To add clarity to the issue, try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof list1);`  I suspect it will report 5.

Answer (score 3):

α and β are not LATIN1. If your file is in UTF-8 encoding these characters need more than one byte and your if statement will not work correctly. In this case you have to compare substrings instead of simple characters.